# Multiprocessing with arguments as dataframes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a list called list1 containing 5 dataframes. I want to pass these dataframes concurrently to a function which would compute some mathematical calculations. I'm struggling with the code below-

```
import multiprocessing 
import pandas as pd

tcn=[df1,df2,df3,df4,df5]

def resampling(tick):
  
    data_k =  tick['price'].resample('1Min').ohlc()
    return data_k


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=len(tcn)) as p:
         results = p.starmap(resampling, tcn)
```

I was getting an error "resampling() takes 1 positional argument but 14 were given" basically 14 is the number of columns in the dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`starmap` is named as such because it applies the subcollections to the function instead of passing them directly:

```
.starmap(f, coll) ~= .map(lambda sub: f(*sub), coll)
```

If you want subcollections to be passed as a single argument, use plain `map` instead.